# Align Radio Buttons and Text Field

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

I'm trying to achieve this

I tried this, I'm not able to align properly kindly let me know what changes that I have to do

```
<apex:outputPanel style="width:100px;backgroung:green" >
    <apex:outputPanel style="float:right" >
        <apex:outputLabel >Test</apex:outputLabel>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel style="float:right" >
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/><input type="text"/> Male <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"/> Female
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Comment: Can you provide a picture of your current visualforce page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the style of `Float:right;` on every outputpanel to get a good look, unless and until you need it. Have added some margin to the styles to align properly. If you are adding some bigger text on the left (where you have Test), you have to increase the margin. Also it depends on the style of parent components and style sheets that you already have

```
<apex:outputPanel style="width:100px;backgroung:green" >
    <apex:outputPanel >
        <apex:outputLabel >Test</apex:outputLabel>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    <apex:outputPanel>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"/><input type="text" style="width:20px;"/> Male <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" style="margin-left:30px;"/> Female
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```